# Opening and working with files in python using one variable

Tags: python, file, variables, printing, variable-assignment

Let's say I have this code:

```
s = open('say.txt').read()
print(s.count('A'))
```

Is it correct to work with the file in this way? I understand that the variable s includes a string from the file. But what happens to the file? Does it close after assigning a value to a variable, or will it be open until the end of the program? And if so, how should it be closed?

I tried to close the file using the close() method, but the executor returned an error.

Comment: The question might be improved by including a listing of the error that is reported when you call s.close().